# Keep Getting Eth0 Error Messages

Tags: virtual-console

I keep getting these error messages with `eth0`:
[image]

Output of `ifconfig`:
[image]

Comment: Is there an ETH0 in your system?  Give the `ifconfig` command without arguments.

Comment: Just updated the post with a pic of it.

Comment: Please try to paste the commands and outputs as code blocks instead of adding screenshots.

Comment: pompsky - Not sure what you mean

Comment: @WillemK  - does this clarify?

Comment: As of version 15.04 Ubuntu moved away from interface naming ETH0. So instead of eth0, your interface is named enp0s3.

Comment: @Zachary.Freese.8 I meant copy lines from Terminal and paste here, don't paste screenshots. [This is how to format codes properly in blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).